# Google Data Studio report using Cloud SQL MySQL allows only one table

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, looker-studio

I'm using Data Studio to generate a financial report dashboard and I'm connecting it to CloudSQL MySQL, but my problem here is that it only requires me one table to use as a data source, and one table wouldn't help me at all to generate a financial report at all.

Here's the image of the process of selecting a Data Source:
[image]

I tried selecting Custom Query, which according to this: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031?hl=en

```
Select the CUSTOM QUERY option to provide a SQL query instead of connecting to a single table. Google Data Studio uses this custom SQL as an inner select statement for each generated query to the database.
```

But I don't know what query should I write to have all my database tables as data sources in Google Data Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding ***Custom Queries***: Had a look online, and didn't seem to find a sample `CUSTOM QUERY` specific to Google Data Studio and [Google Cloud SQL for MySQL](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020436), however, on StackOverflow, there are a couple of posts on BigQuery Custom Queries that involve joins, that may be useful:

- [Data Studio query error when using Big Query view that joins tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142277/data-studio-query-error-when-using-big-query-view-that-joins-tables)
- [BigQuery Data Studio Custom Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114586/bigquery-data-studio-custom-query)

An ***alternative*** is to create individual [Data Sources](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6300774) each linked to a single table and then link multiple Data Sources through the use of [Data Blending](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420), where a common [Join Key](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9194315) links all the respective Tables.

In addition, if you could elaborate on your exact scenario, it would perhaps help users familiar with SQL to provide a more precise solution:

- How are the tables structured?
- How are the tables linked?
- What code have you currently tried?

Answer (score 0):

I also had quite a few issues with the **Custom Query** using the Cloud MySQL Connector by Google for Data Studio.

The resolution for me was to not run `SELECT *` but rather SELECT each column by name.  Not sure why it doesn't like `SELECT *` but hopefully this helps someone else.

#### Example of a successful query.

[image]

#### Example of successful query with join.

[image]